# Use of "(All)" in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Sometimes when I am using VBA to update Pivot Table filters, I use the code

```
.CurrentPage = "(All)"
```

But I just grabbed that piece of the code from someone else without understanding. What does the `"(All)"` here mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(All)" option in a Report Filter is a Default option.

A typical routine to clear the Report Filter field as follows.

```
Sub ClearReportFiltering()
'PURPOSE: How to clear the Report Filter field
 Dim pf As PivotField
 Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Fiscal_Year")

 'Option 1: Clear Out Any Previous Filtering
   pf.ClearAllFilters

 'Option 2: Show All (remove filtering)
   pf.CurrentPage = "(All)"
End Sub
```

You can't remove the (All) option from the report filter's drop-down list, but you can use programming to prevent users from selecting that option.

The following code sample, stored on the OrderDates sheet's module, can undo the report filter change, if (All) is selected or if multiple items are selected in the filter. The macro also shows a message warning -- "Please select a single date."

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim pf As PivotField
On Error GoTo exit_Handler


Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


If ActiveSheet.Name = Me.Name Then

    For Each pf In Target.PageFields
        If pf.CurrentPage = "(All)" Then
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "Please select a single date."
        End If
    Next pf

    End If

exit_Handler:

    Set pf = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Souce : "contextures"

When you select an item from a report filter's drop-down list, the PivotTableUpdate event is triggered. The code checks to see if the (All) item was selected. If it was, the code undoes the change to the report filter, and displays the previously selected item.

**EDIT**
One point still needs elaboration and that is the concept of Pivot table 'page fields' usage. The page fields serve as semi-arbitrary tags on the data ranges that were used. If the data has been collected in an ad-hoc manner and there are various groups, it need to transformed in order to do the analysis within those groups, we need to define the page fields to accommodate it. Where they are really useful is when you are trying to replicate the Grouping features that you can get in a normal Pivot Table. This is done by moving the Page Fields out of the Filters section and down into the Rows or Columns section. If you do that in the order of Page2, Page1, then you will get a nice hierarchical grouping.
   [image: Snapshot showing Page fields in Filter Section]
One Answer by @Byron Wall at Superuser Titled [Pivot table 'page fields' usage](https://superuser.com/questions/918874/pivot-table-page-fields-usage) nicely describes the concept of Pivot Table Page Field.